# Dropdown Date is not updating into database while inserting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

hi friends I have created dropdown dates while inserting user details into database.Here when i input one of the dropdown dates it dosen't get updated into database ,instead it gives default value 1970-01-01.Here i checked in my jquery the line  var end_date=$("#end_date").val() when i give alert for this it dosen;t alert any value for end_date.Can u please point out where i have gone wrong, thank you in advance.
chapter_subscription_search.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$start_date=date("Y-m-d");
?>
<html>
<head><title>Chapter Subscriptions</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header> <img src="images/ipoint.png" class="logo" /> USER REGISTRATION</header>
<div class="container">
<h1 style="text-align:center">ADDING THE CHAPTER SUBSCRIPTION DETAILS</h1>
<style>
#display {
color:red;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
}
.logo {
padding:5px;
float:left;
}
header {
background-color:#074e7c;
height:60px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-size:40px;

}
#wrap {
text-align:center;
}
</style>
<form name="chapter_subscriptions" id="chapter_subscriptions" action="#" method="post">
<table align='center' border='1'>

    <tr>

           <td> <label for="userid">UserId</label></td>
            <td ><input id="userid" name="userid"  type="text" /></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="chapter_no">ChapterNumber</label></td>
        <td ><input id="chapter_no" name="chapter_no" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="start_date">StartDate</label></td>
        <td ><input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="end_date">EndDate</label></td>
        <td ><select name="end_date" id="end_date">
<option value=<?php $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date; ?></option>
<option value=<?php $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date;?> </option>
<option value=<?php $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date;?> </option>

</select>
</td>
        </tr>



      <tr>

           <td> <label for="chap_lic">License</label></td>
           <td ><input id="chap_lic" name="chap_lic" type="text" />  </td>

        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="wrap">
        <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="insert">
        <input type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="edit">
        </div>

        </form>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(e){

        var userid = $("#userid").val();
        var chapter_no = $("#chapter_no").val();
        var start_date = $("#start_date ").val();
        var end_date = $("#end_date").val();
        var chap_lic = $("#chap_lic").val();
        var dataString='userid='+userid+'&chapter_no='+chapter_no+'&start_date='+start_date+'&end_date='+end_date+'&chap_lic='+chap_lic;
        alert(dataString);
        if(userid==""||chapter_no==""||chap_lic=="") {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Enter The Fields";
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chapter_subscription_insert.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    //alert("submitted"+result);
                    $('#display').html(result);

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

            <div id="display">
            </div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

chapter_subscription_insert.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Insert</title></head>
<body>
<?php
include('db.php');
?>
<div id="display">
<?php
$userid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
$chapter_no=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chapter_no']);
$start_date=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start_date']);
$start_date=date("Y-m-d");

$end_date1 = mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['end_date']));


$end_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end_date1));
//echo $end_date;
$chap_lic=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chap_lic']);
$str="insert into chapter_subscriptions(userId,chapter_no,start_date,end_date,chap_lic) values($userid,$chapter_no,'$start_date','$end_date','$chap_lic')";

$query=mysql_query($str);
if($query)
{
    $display="Success";
} else {
    $display="Failed";
}
echo $display;
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the date column's type?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Does dataString not need to be a JSON object for the ajax request?

Comment: Take a look at the `page source` I bet there is no date in the `value=""` attribute of your `<option>` tags

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['end_date']))` there shouldn't be 2 bracket sets here btw.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have that toothache again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856831/dropdown-date-is-not-updating-into-database-while-inserting#comment72819671_42856831) Why need 2 sets of braces

Comment: @RiggsFolly for better bracing? lol no idea. Ok, I'm out.

Comment: Serious you need to take people's comments seriously... all your mysql questions, you have been told to stop using `mysql_*` functions, but u continue using them

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile comments are too often ignored. +1

Comment: @Fred-ii- people are just looking for magic answers, then comeback again the following day ask another question, but what they ask was mentioned in the comments

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile *sigh*, I know this all too well. If they all knew how to "ping" someone, it'd make it all that much more easier for everyone. Then again, many do not know how "Stack rolls" and just post, leave, then come back hoping for what you said; a "magic" answer. *C'est la vie!*

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile [It's happening again...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42857229/)

Answer (score 2):

you have not echoed the values of option:

```
        <select name="end_date" id="end_date">
            <option value=<?php $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date; ?></option>
            <option value=<?php $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date;?> </option>
            <option value=<?php $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date;?> </option>

        </select>
```

change above code to

```
         $enddate1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));
         $enddate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));
         $endate3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));
         <select name="end_date" id="end_date">
             <option value=<?php echo $end_date1; ?>><?php echo $end_date1; ?></option>
             <option value=<?php echo $end_date2; ?>><?php echo $end_date2; ?> </option>
             <option value=<?php echo $end_date3;?>><?php echo $end_date3;?> </option>

        </select>
```

Comment: @Vradhit can u please reply to peoples comments

Answer (score 0):

Error is your dropdown

```
value = "<?php echo $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));?>"

<select name="end_date" id="end_date">
    <option value=<?php echo $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date; ?></option>
    <option value=<?php echo $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date;?> </option>
    <option value=<?php echo $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));?>><?php echo $end_date;?> </option>
</select>
```