# form variables not passing through POST

Tags: php

I'm able to pass all the form values provided in HTML form, but two of them can't read to post.

I can read following values:

```
$fname          = $_POST['fname'];
$lname          = $_POST['lname'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];
$cell           = $_POST['cell'];
$address        = $_POST['address'];
$zip            = $_POST['zip'];
$city           = $_POST['city'];
$program        = $_POST['program'];
```

These two variables always read null values :

```
$location       = $_POST['program2'];
$batch       = $_POST['batch'];
```

This is my html code

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="program" id="program" required>
         <option readonly>Select Your Class</option>
         <option>7</option>
         <option>8</option>
         <option>9</option>
         <option>10</option>
         <option>11</option>
         <option>12</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="program2" id="program2" required>
         <option readonly>Select your Choice</option>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
         <option>4</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="batch" id="batch" required>
         <option readonly>Select Your Choice</option>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>21</option>`enter code here`
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is elsewhere, that all looks fine to me

Comment: @Steve I am confused...does his html code relates to php code and his problem??

Comment: you are not passing values in option

Comment: Lord only knows (and you) if there's a form somewhere and if there's an explicit POST method.

Comment: the question's unclear and as to how you are then using `$location` and `$batch`.

Answer (score -1):

You should add 'value' attribute to the option tag. Something like this:

`<option value = "1">1</option>`

Comment: So, explain why they didn't have a problem with their `<select class="form-control" name="program" id="program" required>`.

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing value attribute to the option list. Your code should be as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="program" id="program" required>
                        <option value="" readonly>Select Your Class</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="program2" id="program2" required>
                        <option value="" readonly>Select your Choice</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>                               
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="batch" id="batch" required>
                        <option value="" readonly>Select Your Choice</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>`enter code here`

                    </select>
                </div>
For more reference you could check the below links:
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

```
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp
```

Comment: So, explain why they didn't have a problem with their `<select class="form-control" name="program" id="program" required>`.